# Adding click event to HTML5 template

Tags: javascript, html

How do you add a click event to a html5 template tag?

The following never registers a click event with the image:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <template id="itemTemplate">
        foo
        <img id='imageTag' src='image.png'>
    </template>
    <script>
        var templ = document.querySelector('#itemTemplate');
        templ.content.querySelector('#imageTag').click = function(){alert('xxxx');};
        var content = document.querySelector('#content');
        content.appendChild(templ.content.cloneNode(true));
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Not `.click` but `.onclick`

Comment: You don't. A template is simply a non functioning, non visible piece of markup that can be cloned and used as a template. Attach the event handler to the clone.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same problem myself, and I will write what I have learned so others will have an answer as well.

As adenine commented, it's impossible to do it from inside the template. I tried that as well. What you could do, is complete the template creation, and when all the elements are registered in the DOM, you could add event listeners then.

So your code will look like:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<template id="itemTemplate">
    foo
    <img id='imageTag' src='image.png'>
</template>
<script>
    var templ = document.querySelector('#itemTemplate');
    var content = document.querySelector('#content');
    content.appendChild(templ.content.cloneNode(true));
    document.querySelector('#imageTag').click = function(){alert('xxxx');};
</script>
```

I used to have the same problem when I needed to add event listeners to an array of elements (trying to dynamically build a paginator), so I have used a forEach loop to give each element its click event:

```
    for (var i = 0 ; i < totalPages ; i++) {
        anchorElement.innerHTML = i + 1;
        anchorElement.dataset.pageId = i + 1;
        var clone = document.importNode(templateElement.content, true);
        paginationContainer.appendChild(clone);
    }

    // Register pagination event listeners
    document.querySelectorAll('.pagination a').forEach(function(anchorElement) {
        $(anchorElement).on('click', function() {
            alert('Hello');
        });
    });
```